# $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n}$ fails the p-series test, but passes the alternating series test?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, power-series

[P-Series Reference](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/PowerSeries.aspx)

[Alternating Series Test Reference](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/AlternatingSeries.aspx)

$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n} $$

This alternating series fails the p-series test because the exponent of $n$ is equal to $1$.

Yet it seems to pass the alternating series test.

1 - $a_n$ must be positive. True.

2 - Terms must be decreasing. $\frac{d}{dn} 1/n = -n^{-2}$, which is < 1. True.

3 - $ \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} 1/n = 0  $ True.

$\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$ is clearly a divergent series, so why does it pass the AST?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

What you are noting is that the series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \,\frac{(-1)^n}{n}\quad {\bf {converges},}$$ as you found by the *alternating series test*, *but does not converge **absolutely***: $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \,\left|\frac{(-1)^n}{n}\right| \quad = \quad \sum_{n = 1}^\infty\,\frac 1n\quad\bf{does\; not\; converge.}$$

Note: the $p$-series test is applicable for sums of the form: $\displaystyle\sum \frac 1{n^{p}},$ and your "given" series does not "fit" that form for odd $n$; indeed, the most appropriate test to use here, as you used in the end, is the *alternating series test*.

Comment: +1 from me, but I let my answer stand as a cautionary tale of sorts.

Comment: What is the value of the series $$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n} $$? Can you  provide some references?

Comment: What is Series expansion of logx ?

Comment: @https://math.stackexchange.com/users/505767/user, don't make trivial edits to posts over 10 years old.

Comment: @amWhy I edited your answer because I noticed that the index should be $n$ (or $i$ should be used in the sum) and it should start from $1$.

Comment: @amWhy I noticed it because I was answering to a new question which have thisone as target duplicate.

Comment: @amWhy The same issue was in the original question. It is really funny it wasn't recognized in over ten years!

Comment: (I didn't downvote but I think the answer should be edited)

Answer (score 11):

What you seem to be missing is this: What you call the power series test merely *fails to prove that the series converges*. It does not prove that the series diverges, absolutely or otherwise. The alternating series test, on the other hand, proves that the series does converge.

Comment: That's not true: the p-series test does prove divergence for series of the form $\sum \frac 1{n^p}$ when $p\leq 1$.

Comment: @amWhy: Sure, but how did the p-series test enter into the discussion?

Comment: Look at  the title for the question.

Comment: @amWhy: Oh, the *title*, eh? Well, there should be a law against mentioning relevant information *only* in the title. He clearly said “power series test” in the question body – a term which could be taken to mean any test which yields the radious of convergence, but not by any stretch of the imagination to include the p-series test.

Comment: I understand completely...Argh!! mismatching questions/titles!

Comment: I guess I didn't realize that there was a difference between "p-series test" and "power series test," I thought they meant the same thing.

Comment: Ok, so I am starting the section on power series and the radius of convergence for a power series and I see why the original wording of the question was ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

We have that

$$\sum_{n = 1}^{2N} \frac{(-1)^n}{n}=\sum_{n = 1}^{N} \frac{1}{2n}- \sum_{n = 1}^{N}\frac{1}{2n-1}$$

with

$$\sum_{n = 1}^{N}\frac{1}{2n-1}=\sum_{n = 1}^{2N-1}\frac1n-\sum_{n = 1}^{N-1}\frac{1}{2n}$$

therefore

$$\sum_{n = 1}^{2N} \frac{(-1)^n}{n}=\frac1{2N}+\sum_{n = 1}^{N-1}\frac1n-\sum_{n = 1}^{2N-1}\frac1n$$

and by harmonic series with $H_n=\sum_{n = 1}^{N} \frac{1}{n}=\log N+\gamma+O\left(\frac1N\right)$ we finally have

$$\sum_{n = 1}^{2N} \frac{(-1)^n}{n}=\log (N-1)-\log (2N-1)+O\left(\frac1N\right)=$$

$$=\log \left(\frac{N-1}{2N-1}\right)+O\left(\frac1N\right)\to \log \frac12$$

Comment: That is not enough. Indeed, being the series conditionally convergent, one can get any real number by simply changing the order of summation. What you have shown is that a particular grouping converges. In order to show the convergence of the original series, it is necessary to show something more. For example, the convergence of $\sum_{n = 1}^{2N}+1 \frac{(-1)^n}{n}$, as done in https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test

Comment: @GiorgioP-DoomsdayClockIsAt-90 Thanks for the comment! I think you are right ;)

Comment: @GiorgioP-DoomsdayClockIsAt-90 I've updated with an alternative proof.